# Does Apple Pay require an internet connection?

Tags: apple-pay

Do I need an internet connection on my iPhone 6 to use Apple Pay?

Comment: It uses NFC technology, there are more cards and devices without internet using NFC.

Comment: @Rob just because it uses NFC doesn't mean it works offline. HCE uses NFC and in some setups it only works a limited number of times while offline. http://www.androidauthority.com/everything-need-know-host-card-emulation-347626/

Answer (score 9):

No, Apple Pay does not require an internet connection.  Apple Pay uses [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) technology; it does not use Wi-Fi or cellular technology.

According to [CNet](http://www.cnet.com/news/everything-you-want-to-know-about-apple-pay/), Apple Pay will work even if you put your iPhone 6 into Airplane Mode.  Airplane Mode disables both the Wi-Fi and cellular internet.

Comment: It will also work on a paired Apple Watch without its host iPhone around.

Comment: Just because it uses NFC does not mean it works w/o a connection by default as witnessed by Android HCE payments which uses NFC but only allows a few payments in-between connections.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes and no.

Internet connectivity is required for any setup or maintenance of your cards.  Once a card has been successfully added to the device, the phone can be disconnected for payments, which is a local interaction between the device and the point of sale terminal.

Answer (score 6):

No, Apple Pay can be used an unlimited number of times while offline since it generates payment information locally as opposed to some other mobile payments like HCE which only allow a [limited number of payments](http://www.androidauthority.com/everything-need-know-host-card-emulation-347626/) in-between getting an internet connection.

Apple Support article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201469